# How to offset a square so that it's side is aligned with another rectangles diagonal?

Tags: geometry

I'm making some 3d math stuff and I got stuck this problem:

Let's say I have a rectangle of a size a=2 and b=3, and a square whose side is a sum of the rectangles sides (so 5 now). Both shapes have a center in the same point.

I calculate the alpha angle of the rectangles diagonal and rotate the square by that angle (think it was 33.6˚ in this case).

Next I want to offset the square on the x and y axis by some value so it's aligned with the rectangles diagonal. And I can't figure out how to calculate that value.

[image]

Comment: I think you can slide the square left by $c/2$ first, then rotate it.

Comment: @EthanBolker true, but I'm somewhat limited in the location of the pivot point of the square. The pivot is located in the centre of the square, so I can only rotate around that.